# RecyclerView ViewHolder goes to the wrong custom adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, realm, android-adapter

based on same example I've implemented, I create a custom adapter of my RecyclerView. The code is this:

```
public class AirportsAdapter extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<Airport,RecyclerView.ViewHolder> implements Filterable
{
Context context;
public static final int FILTER_MODE_A = 0;
public static final int FILTER_MODE_B = 1;
OrderedRealmCollection<Airport> listAirports;
RealmResults<Airport> nearby;
Realm realm;

int NEARBY = 0;
int nearbySize;
boolean COUNTRY = false;
int ALL = 0;

public AirportsAdapter(Context context, OrderedRealmCollection<Airport>airports, RealmResults<Airport> nearby, Realm realm)
{
    super(context,airports, true);
    this.context = context;
    this.listAirports = airports;
    this.realm = realm;
    this.nearby = nearby;

    nearbySize = nearby.size();
    ALL = ALL + nearbySize;

}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{

    //sono tutti uguali no?
    //sisi l'avevo messo così solo per non fare un mega or

   if(viewType == 0 || viewType== ALL || (viewType == 0 && (COUNTRY)))
    {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.input_custom_item, parent, false);
        MenuHolder menuHolder = new MenuHolder(view);
        return menuHolder;
    }

    else
    {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.airport_show, parent, false);
        AirportClass holder = new AirportClass(view);
        return holder;
    }

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
{
   if(position==0)
    {
        MenuHolder mHolder = (MenuHolder)holder;
        mHolder.type.setText("Nearby");
        mHolder.type.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/Avenir-Medium.ttf"),Typeface.BOLD);

    }

   else if(position == ALL)
   {
       MenuHolder mHolder = (MenuHolder)holder;
       mHolder.type.setText("All");
       mHolder.type.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/Avenir-Medium.ttf"),Typeface.BOLD);
   }

   else if(position == 0 && (COUNTRY))
   {
       MenuHolder mHolder = (MenuHolder)holder;
       mHolder.type.setText("Country");
       mHolder.type.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/Avenir-Medium.ttf"),Typeface.BOLD);
   }

   else
   {
        AirportClass mHolder = (AirportClass) holder;

        Airport airport = listAirports.get(position);

        String country = airport.getIsoCountry().toLowerCase();


        if (country.equals("do"))
            country = "dom";

        int imgID = context.getResources().getIdentifier(country, "drawable", context.getPackageName());



        Glide.with(context).load(imgID).into(mHolder.image);

        mHolder.des.setText(airport.getIdent());
        mHolder.name.setText(airport.getName());

        mHolder.des.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Avenir-Book.ttf"), Typeface.BOLD);
        mHolder.name.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Avenir-Book.ttf"));
    }
}

public void filterResults(String text, int filterMode)
{
    String txt = text;
    text = text == null ? null : text.toLowerCase().trim();
    if(text == null || "".equals(text))
    {
        listAirports = realm.where(Airport.class).findAll();
    }
    else
    {
        if(filterMode == FILTER_MODE_A)
        {
            listAirports = realm.where(Airport.class).contains("name", text, Case.INSENSITIVE).findAll();
            COUNTRY = false;
        }
        if(filterMode == FILTER_MODE_B)
        {
            System.out.print(text);
            COUNTRY = true;
            Countries country = realm.where(Countries.class).equalTo("name",txt).findFirst();
            listAirports = realm.where(Airport.class).equalTo("isoCountry", country.getCode(), Case.INSENSITIVE).findAll();

        }
    }
    updateData(listAirports);
}


public Filter getFilter(int filterMode)
{
    AirportFilter filter = new AirportFilter(this, filterMode);
    return filter;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {

    return null;
}


private class AirportFilter extends Filter
{
    private final AirportsAdapter adapter;
    private int filterMode;

    private AirportFilter(AirportsAdapter adapter, int filterMode)
    {
        super();
        this.adapter = adapter;
        this.filterMode = filterMode;
    }


    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint)
    {
        if (filterMode == FILTER_MODE_A)
            return new Filter.FilterResults();
        if (filterMode == FILTER_MODE_B)
            return new Filter.FilterResults();

        return new Filter.FilterResults();
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results)
    {
        adapter.filterResults(constraint.toString(),filterMode);
    }
}


private class AirportClass extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    TextView name, des;
    ImageView image;

    public AirportClass(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);

        name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        des = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item);
        image = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.color);

    }
}

private class MenuHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    TextView type;
    public MenuHolder(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        type = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.init);
    }
}

}
```

it is similar to other adapter, but when I debug it, I have this error:

```
 Process: com.example, PID: 1663
              java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.Airports.AirportsAdapter$MenuHolder cannot be cast to com.example.Airports.AirportsAdapter$AirportClass
                  at com.example.Airports.AirportsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(AirportsAdapter.java:118)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6279)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6312)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5258)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5521)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5363)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5359)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2141)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1525)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1488)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:585)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3506)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:2969)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19730)
                  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
                  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19730)
                  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
                  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19730)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
                  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:714)
                  at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
                  at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1375)
                  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:784)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19730)
                  at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1081)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19730)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19730)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19730)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19730)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19730)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:687)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19730)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2271)
```

and this is the first time I have this error, and I try to solve it but I could fix it only in these ways:

1. delete MenuHolder and use only AirportClass or
2. delete AirportClass and use only MenuHolder

Is there a way to solve this error?

**EDIT:** this is new code, it does not give the previous error but it stay in the state of position ==0ç

```
public class AirportsAdapter extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<Airport,RecyclerView.ViewHolder> implements Filterable
{
Context context;
public static final int FILTER_MODE_A = 0;
public static final int FILTER_MODE_B = 1;
OrderedRealmCollection<Airport> listAirports;
RealmResults<Airport> nearby;
Realm realm;

int NEARBY = 0;
int nearbySize;
boolean COUNTRY = false;
int ALL = 0;

public AirportsAdapter(Context context, OrderedRealmCollection<Airport>airports, RealmResults<Airport> nearby, Realm realm)
{
    super(context,airports, true);
    this.context = context;
    this.listAirports = airports;
    this.realm = realm;
    this.nearby = nearby;

    nearbySize = nearby.size();
    ALL = ALL + nearbySize;

}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{

    //sono tutti uguali no?
    //sisi l'avevo messo così solo per non fare un mega or

   if(viewType == NEARBY )
    {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.input_custom_item, parent, false);
        MenuHolder menuHolder = new MenuHolder(view);
        return menuHolder;
    }

    else
    {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.airport_show, parent, false);
        AirportClass holder = new AirportClass(view);
        return holder;
    }

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
{
   if(getItemViewType(position)==NEARBY)
    {
        Log.i("ivt",String.valueOf(position));
        MenuHolder mHolder = (MenuHolder)holder;
        mHolder.type.setText("Nearby");
        mHolder.type.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/Avenir-Medium.ttf"),Typeface.BOLD);

    }

/*   else if(getItemViewType(position) == ALL)
   {
       MenuHolder mHolder = (MenuHolder)holder;
       mHolder.type.setText("All");
       mHolder.type.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/Avenir-Medium.ttf"),Typeface.BOLD);
   }

   else if(getItemViewType(position) == 0 && (COUNTRY))
   {
       MenuHolder mHolder = (MenuHolder)holder;
       mHolder.type.setText("Country");
       mHolder.type.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/Avenir-Medium.ttf"),Typeface.BOLD);
   }
   */
   else
   {
        AirportClass mHolder = (AirportClass) holder;

        Airport airport = listAirports.get(position);

        String country = airport.getIsoCountry().toLowerCase();


        if (country.equals("do"))
            country = "dom";

        int imgID = context.getResources().getIdentifier(country, "drawable", context.getPackageName());



        Glide.with(context).load(imgID).into(mHolder.image);

        mHolder.des.setText(airport.getIdent());
        mHolder.name.setText(airport.getName());

        mHolder.des.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Avenir-Book.ttf"), Typeface.BOLD);
        mHolder.name.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Avenir-Book.ttf"));
    }
}


@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position)
{
    return super.getItemViewType(position);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    if(nearbySize == 0)
    {
        return 1 + listAirports.size();
    }
    else
    {
      return 2 + nearbySize + listAirports.size();
    }
}

public void filterResults(String text, int filterMode)
{
    String txt = text;
    text = text == null ? null : text.toLowerCase().trim();
    if(text == null || "".equals(text))
    {
        listAirports = realm.where(Airport.class).findAll();
    }
    else
    {
        if(filterMode == FILTER_MODE_A)
        {
            listAirports = realm.where(Airport.class).contains("name", text, Case.INSENSITIVE).findAll();
            COUNTRY = false;
        }
        if(filterMode == FILTER_MODE_B)
        {
            System.out.print(text);
            COUNTRY = true;
            Countries country = realm.where(Countries.class).equalTo("name",txt).findFirst();
            listAirports = realm.where(Airport.class).equalTo("isoCountry", country.getCode(), Case.INSENSITIVE).findAll();

        }
    }
    updateData(listAirports);
}


public Filter getFilter(int filterMode)
{
    AirportFilter filter = new AirportFilter(this, filterMode);
    return filter;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {

    return null;
}


private class AirportFilter extends Filter
{
    private final AirportsAdapter adapter;
    private int filterMode;

    private AirportFilter(AirportsAdapter adapter, int filterMode)
    {
        super();
        this.adapter = adapter;
        this.filterMode = filterMode;
    }


    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint)
    {
        if (filterMode == FILTER_MODE_A)
            return new Filter.FilterResults();
        if (filterMode == FILTER_MODE_B)
            return new Filter.FilterResults();

        return new Filter.FilterResults();
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results)
    {
        adapter.filterResults(constraint.toString(),filterMode);
    }
}


private class AirportClass extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    TextView name, des;
    ImageView image;

    public AirportClass(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);

        name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        des = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item);
        image = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.color);

    }
}

private class MenuHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    TextView type;
    public MenuHolder(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        type = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.init);
    }
 }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: `position == ALL` How does that work? Your position will never equal the size of the list

Comment: Also, you never overwrite the method that gets an item viewtype

Comment: ALL is the sum of 0 + nearby.size() and nearby is a subList of listAirports

Comment: @cricket_007 I've also tried only with condition if(viewType == 0) and it doesn't work in the same way

Comment: I think you should overwrite getItemViewType and not sure about ` && (COUNTRY)` because that's never entered. And ALL is a confusing name. If it's a sublist, only one view in the adapter has that holder?

Comment: COUNTRY is a flag that could enter if the originalList is filtered by countryName, so I've implemented it

Comment: The sublist need to ne printed before the original list, but using the same custom xml

Comment: Is your error happening when country is true or false?

Comment: It not goes in this condition, it gives me error when goes to the first if condition of the view holder

Comment: Yes, the error exists in `onBindViewHolder` but only because your conditionals are messed up in the method that creates the holder

Comment: so now I use gemItemViewType( ) and rewrite conditions?

Comment: You can try, I don't know if it'll fix your error.

Comment: @cricket_007 now it does not crashes, but I have some other problems

Comment: Any progress is good progress, IMO

Comment: @cricket_007 the problem is that goes in if (position ==0) when position =1

Comment: Well, logically that doesn't make sense, so I'm not sure what you are trying to in order to see that

Comment: @cricket_007 I've edited question

Comment: Your `getItemViewType` method only returns one number. Please change your that to return the correct types of NEARBY or ALL depending on position

Comment: @cricket_007 but I print getItemViewType(position) and in every row it prints number correctly like 0,1,2,3..etc

Comment: Okay, but when you check the viewtypes, you only seem to check NEARBY which is 0. By returning the super method, you aren't saying that NEARBY is an expected type

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks for your help, now it works!

Comment: Cool. Feel free to provide your working code as an answer below